# Where I can find ncso.jar?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I am trying to develop an application, which will remotely connected to a Lotusnote server and as I got to know, I should have ncso.jar file to add in my application for enabling remote access to the Lotus Note domino server. So would be appreciated to help me for downloading this file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find ncso.jar in installed Notes Client or Domino Server directory in folder

> ... / data / domino / java