# Where can I get Notes.jar or NCSO.jar?

Tags: java, jar, lotus-notes, lotus

I want to write a java program which automatically sends via my local client mails via the lotus notes api.

For this project I added the [domingo-1.5 libary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/domingo/) to my classpath.

However, when running my test program I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" de.bea.domingo.service.NotesServiceRuntimeException: One of Notes.jar or NCSO.jar must be in classpath
    at de.bea.domingo.service.NotesServiceFactory.throwWrappedException(NotesServiceFactory.java:335)
    at de.bea.domingo.service.NotesServiceFactory.<init>(NotesServiceFactory.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at de.bea.domingo.DNotesFactoryFinder.newInstance(DNotesFactoryFinder.java:116)
    at de.bea.domingo.DNotesFactoryFinder.find(DNotesFactoryFinder.java:73)
    at de.bea.domingo.DNotesFactory.newInstance(DNotesFactory.java:155)
    at de.bea.domingo.DNotesFactory.getInstance(DNotesFactory.java:82)
    at NLotus.main(NLotus.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lotus/domino/NotesException
    at de.bea.domingo.service.NotesServiceFactory.<init>(NotesServiceFactory.java:135)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lotus.domino.NotesException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
```

Any recommendations where I can get the `Notes.jar` or `NCSO.jar`?

I would appreciate your replies!

Comment: I suppose you need to install the Lotus Notes client...

Comment: From the vendor, see this [page](http://domingo.sourceforge.net/download.html) (System Requirements).

Comment: It's part of the IBM Notes client install - see for instance this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26529701/785061

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something you should notice first:
(1)You can only run this program in the computer where Lotus nodes has been installed.
(2)You don't need to add Notes.jar into your project's classpath.

What you need to do is to locate Notes.jar in the lib folder where Lotus nodes installed, set the system 'Classpath' to include that jar's location(in window environment, you can configure this in environment setting). Finally, the program should run successfully.

Comment: That's true for Notes.jar, but the question also asks about NCSO.jar, and that is intended for use on machines that do not have Lotus Notes installed. You can take it from a valid Notes or Domino installation and copy it any other machine with a compatible JVM.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Domino in Window, you should find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Domino\jvm\lib\ext\Notes.jar