# Making local calls from Tomcat 7 to Domino 9

Tags: java, tomcat, lotus-domino

I already tried to solve this problem the whole day, but haven't found a solution.

I want to run an web application on Tomcat 7 that does local calls to a Domino 9 Server on the same machine.

My starting point was: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/DIIOP_Usage_and_Troubleshooting_Guide and other articles it links to.

The Server has Ubuntu 14.04 as OS.
I already solved, all the binding errors by changing **/etc/default/tomcat7**

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.library.path=/opt/ibm/lotus/notes/latest/linux"

#NOTES_DATA_DIR=/srvmuc202_data
PATH=$PATH:/opt/ibm/lotus/notes/latest/linux:/srvmuc202_data
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ibm/lotus/notes/latest/linux
#CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/ibm/lotus/notes/latest/linux/jvm/lib/ext/Notes.jar
```

The notes.ini is located in the data directory. The only way I found to access it, was adding it to path.

I was not able to change the CLASSPATH properly. That's why it's commented. Tomcat ignores this setting if active.
**Edit:** <del>I solved it, by adding the Notes.jar to my WAR file.</del>
I use the installed Notes.jar now. It works because I created a symlink to Notes.jar wihtin the Tomcat lib directory `/usr/share/tomcat7/lib`

Here is my test code:

```
NotesThread.sinitThread();
Session session = null;
Database db = null;
try {
    session = NotesFactory.createSession();
    if (session != null) {
        log.debug("Session available");
        log.debug("Servername: {}", session.getServerName());
        log.debug("Effective user name: {}", session.getEffectiveUserName());
        log.debug("User name: {}", session.getUserName());
        log.debug("Common user name: {}", session.getCommonUserName());
        log.debug("Notes version: {}", session.getNotesVersion());
        db = session.getDatabase("", "mbur/mburchard.nsf", false);
        if (db != null && db.isOpen()) {
            log.debug("Got database: {}", db.getTitle());
        }
    }
} catch (NotesException e) {
    log.error("", e);
} finally {
    recycle(db);
    recycle(session);
}
NotesThread.stermThread();
```

Without adding data directory to the path my application works, but has no access to anything. The output is then:

```
[23606:00002-965273344] Error writing to process file pid.nbf, (other applications may be inappropriately accessing this file)
15:43:45.859 [http-bio-7080-exec-1] DEBUG de.mbur.billing.impl.TestNotes - Session available
15:43:45.859 [http-bio-7080-exec-1] DEBUG de.mbur.billing.impl.TestNotes - Servername: 
15:43:45.859 [http-bio-7080-exec-1] DEBUG de.mbur.billing.impl.TestNotes - Effective user name: 
15:43:45.859 [http-bio-7080-exec-1] DEBUG de.mbur.billing.impl.TestNotes - User name: 
15:43:45.859 [http-bio-7080-exec-1] DEBUG de.mbur.billing.impl.TestNotes - Common user name: 
15:43:45.859 [http-bio-7080-exec-1] DEBUG de.mbur.billing.impl.TestNotes - Notes version: Release 9.0.1FP2HF385 | November 4, 2014
```

I think, it's because it doesn't know about the notes.ini nor the Domino server id file.

**Edit**
I added Tomcat to the Domino Servers group and now the err 258 is gone.
Now it behaves the same as without knowing the notes.ini.
No effective username, no access to anything.

<del>With the data directory in the path I get an error message:</del>

```
15:48:22.650 [http-bio-7080-exec-1] ERROR d.mbur.billing.impl.PersonController - 
java.lang.Exception: Notes initialization failure - err 258
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.NnotesInitThread(Native Method) ~[Notes.jar:na]
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.sinitThread(Unknown Source) ~[Notes.jar:na]
    at de.mbur.billing.impl.TestNotes.run(TestNotes.java:18) ~[TestNotes.class:na]
    at de.mbur.billing.impl.PersonController.greeting(PersonController.java:49) ~[PersonController.class:na]
```

I appreciate any help to get Domino 9 access from Tomcat 7 running the right way.
Ideally without adidng Notes.jar to the WAR file and running with full server rights.

Comment: If you want to use DIIOP, you need to use ncso.jar instead of notes.jar.  The two jars have different implementations of the same interfaces.  The classes in ncso.jar are used to access a Domino server remotely through DIIOP.  See this link for information about locating ncso.jar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529625/where-i-can-find-ncso-jar

Comment: But if it's truly local, with Domino and Tomcat running on the same machine, it certainly makes a lot of sense to be using notes.jar.

Comment: It's truly local, that's why I use Notes.jar. It's explained here, when to use Notes and NCSO: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Java_access_pt1/index.html  
Both is called DIIOP...

Comment: @Nabor, I agree it makes sense to use notes.jar.  In that case, DIIOP is not involved.  Perhaps you should restate the question.

Comment: Re "Both is called DIIOP", no it's only called DIIOP when you are using NCSO.jar. Dave is right. When you are using Notes.jar, you are using NRPC connecting to the regular Domino server task on port 1352.  When you use NCSO.jar, it is connecting to the Domino IIOP task on the IIOP port (usually 60148 or 63148).

Comment: Where is the lsxbe library located? (It's nlsxbe.dll on windows; I don't have a Linux machine handy to check the naming convention there.)

Comment: It's under '/opt/ibm/lotus/notes/latest/linux'. Indeed I don't see binding errors. But I don't have Server rights. I'll update the description...

Comment: In summary, you are able to get an instance of Session, but there doesn't seem to be a user identity associated with it and you can't open a database.  Does your server ID file have a password?  Also, have you tried running the Tomcat code without the Domino server running?

Comment: Correct summary. I tried you idea running Tomcat without Domino. Same effekt. It get's a session without any rights. The Server ID has no password.

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer for you.  I would need to try a similar set up, but I simply don't have the time.  Btw, I sort of expected you would get the same results when the Domino server is not running.  In your set up, the Notes code in the Tomcat process doesn't really need the Domino server to be running.  It should be running as the Domino server ID.  I can't imagine why that's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a break I had time to test and solve this problem.

It was a really small detail. Write rights for the Domino group!

I'd like to take this answer as chance to write a complete guide.

**Howto access Domino from Tomcat on the same machine**

Tomcat (or any other Program that runs your Java Code) should be in the Domino group, that is normally named ***notes***
Make sure, that this Domino group has read **and write** rights on everything in the notes data directory.

Change the Tomcat configuration (under Ubuntu 14.04 available at **/etc/default/tomcat7**)

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.library.path=/opt/ibm/domino/notes/latest/linux"

PATH=$PATH:/opt/ibm/lotus/notes/latest/linux:/local/notesdata
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ibm/domino/notes/latest/linux
```

Link to the Notes.jar by switching into the directory **/usr/share/tomcat7/lib** and creating a symlink.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/ibm/domino/notes/latest/linux/jvm/lib/ext/Notes.jar
```

Deploy your WAR file to Tomcat and be happy :)